# How do I use slicers to display rows inbetween two seperate values?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

I'm trying to filter **Table 1** using two slicers where I can choose:

- A value from the "*From"* column
- A value from the *"To"* column

As a result I want to display all rows in between these two values even if the *From* and *To* columns don't include any of the chosen values. **Table 2** is how I would want the output to be if I were to choose the value **A** from the *From* slicer and **D** from the *To* slicer.

**Table 1:**

| ID | SentDate | From | To | ArrivalDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.23 12:00 | A | B | 01.01.23 12:10 |
| 1 | 01.01.23 12:00 | B | C | 01.01.23 12:20 |
| 1 | 01.01.23 12:00 | C | D | 01.01.23 12:30 |
| 1 | 01.01.23 12:00 | D | E | 01.01.23 12:40 |
| 1 | 01.01.23 12:00 | E | F | 01.01.23 12:50 |

**Table 2:**

| ID | SentDate | From | To | ArrivalDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.23 12:00 | A | B | 01.01.23 12:10 |
| 1 | 01.01.23 12:00 | B | C | 01.01.23 12:20 |
| 1 | 01.01.23 12:00 | C | D | 01.01.23 12:30 |

Comment: Are the values ordered with unitary distance as per example or different?

Comment: Can you update your table as copiable text?

Comment: @EnricoBelvisi the values are ordered by the ArrivalDate

Comment: @DavideBacci It should be copiable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do a *between* selection, you need a continuous value (dates, numbers). For your use case, the following will work.

Create two new tables as follows:

```
From = ALLNOBLANKROW(Table1[From])

To = ALLNOBLANKROW(Table1[To])
```

[image]

[image]

Make sure there are no relationships between these new tables and your existing table.

Add two slicers using your new tables:

[image]

Add a measure as follows:

```
Measure = 

VAR f = UNICODE(SELECTEDVALUE('From'[From]))
VAR t = UNICODE( SELECTEDVALUE('To'[To]))
RETURN 
IF(UNICODE(SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[From])) >= f && UNICODE(SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[To])) <= t, 1)
```

Add the measure to the filter pane of you table visual as follows (set it equal to 1):

[image]

Your slicers will now work.

[image]